# Passing multiple parameters via json.stringify/ajax not working

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have tried searching through SO for an answer to my issue, but all the posts I find still aren't helping me resolve my issue.  I don't know if I am overlooking something or if it's just my lack of knowledge that is preventing  my code from working.

I have two JS prompts that ask for an ID and then an amount to adjust my stock level.  I want it to pass that along to my php file to run a mysql update query.

My script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendArray()
{
    var ourObj = {};
    ourObj.itemId = prompt("Scan ID:");
    ourObj.adjAmt = prompt("Enter amount:");
    alert(ourObj.itemId);
    alert(ourObj.adjAmt);
    $.ajax({
        url: "save.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { invAdj : JSON.stringify(ourObj)},
        success: function(response)
            {
                alert("data sent response is "+response);
            },
        error: function(e)
            {
                alert("data not sent"+e);
            }
    });
}
</script>
<button onclick="sendArray();">Send Array</button>
```

My php:

```
if(isset($_POST['invAdj'])) {
    $invAdj = json_decode($_POST['invAdj']);
    $itemId = $invAdj->itemId;
    $amtAdj = $invAdj->amtAdj;

}
mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE stock_levels SET stocklevel  = stocklevel + " . $amtAdj . " WHERE id = " . $itemId);
?>
```

Presently, I get a successful alert, but the level does not change in the db.  I know that the db info works and the sql query works because if comment out the post block an add solid variables, it runs perfectly.  I have something screwed up in the POST block.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Again, sorry if this has been answered, but I couldn't find a post that worked...

Also, I know that I shouldn't put the SQL directly into my query.  I am just trying to get this working first.

Thanks

Comment: In your javascript, you use the variable `adjAmt` but in PHP you're looking for `amtAdj`. I recommend renaming it to `adjust` or something easier to read :)

Comment: You are awesome.  This dyslexia is going to kill me...  Thank you so much! Three hours wasted to something so simple :/

Comment: The data may be coming in as raw input vs `$_POST` array elements.  What happens if you `print_r($_POST);` ? Do you see the variables you are expecting?  If not, then try reading raw input and seeing what is there - `$input=file_get_contents("php://input");`

Comment: @Tutoro we've all been there! I avoid using shortened words now because I've done the same thing many times

Comment: I will try these tomorrow and report back.  Thanks!  Tried to upvote you all, but mobile SO giving an error when I try.

Comment: @mulquin your catch fixed my issue! Thank you very much!